# Global import of modules with Jest and Spectator

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, jestjs, angular-spectator, spectator

In my Angular project, I have removed Karma in order to use Jest.js with Spectator instead. It works well, but now, as the module related to translations is a bit verbose, I am trying to import it globally. I read in the [documentation](https://github.com/ngneat/spectator#global-injections) of Spectator this can be done in test.js, but unless I am mistaken, that file is used by Karma, not by Jest.js. So I would like to know if it is possible to do global injections with Jest/Spectator, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those using Jest, the global injections should be set in `setupJest.ts`

Example:

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

import { defineGlobalsInjections } from '@ngneat/spectator';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

defineGlobalsInjections({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: wrote an article about this some time ago https://developapa.com/angular-jest-karma-config/